# Cannot go back to primary screen on laptop

Tags: windows-7, laptop, multiple-monitors

I have a dual screen connected to my win7 laptop, it is set to only display the projector and keep the primary screen(laptop screen) blank. How do I remove/disable the projector screen (dual screen) and go back to having a display only on Laptop screen.

I have tried win+P and selecting 'Disconnect Projector' and then removing the second monitor cable, a few times, but it doesn't work. Laptop screen remains blank and when I reconnect secondary screen I can see normal display on it.

I also tried selecting 'Extend display' but nothing appeared on Laptop screen. Same result when selected 'show desktop only on 1'. I'm quite sure there is nothing wrong with laptop screen.

I'm sorry if this has been asked before but I have tried a whole bunch of suggestions and nothing seems to work. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you restarted the computer? If you look at Display Properties does it show the laptop display active and connected?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did restart while trying each of the above mentioned steps. Under display properties, I see both the screens. The laptop screen is labeled as 'Mobile PC Display'.

Comment: Can you move your mouse or windows onto the blank screen? We're trying to determine if the screen itself is not working. You can tell if this is the case if you can move items onto the screen, even if the screen is blank.

Comment: No, I cannot move my mouse to the laptop screen. Though when I select win+P followed by 'Duplicate'. The secondary screen changes to same resolution as laptop screen(I remember this from before), may be this means it can somehow detect laptop screen and its properties.

Comment: I completely lose the mouse when I do win+P followed by Extend, in this the laptop screen becomes the primary but remains blank . I can however use the keyboard shortcuts to move windows around etc. but the mouse doesnt show up.

Comment: That means your laptop screen is on but is not working. This is a hardware fault. If the laptop is under warranty please contact the manufacturer for assistance.